# How can i get Ids from li tags using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is html code :

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="attachments[183]"></li>
    <li id="attachments[196]"></li>
    <li id="attachments[145]"></li>
    <li id="attachments[545]"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is JavaScript/jQuery code :

```
var query = {
    'action'  : 'save-attachment-order',
    'nonce'   : '8cb16e3927',
    'post_id' :  89,
}
```

I want to get li IDs and make it this var like this

```
var query = {
    'action'  : 'save-attachment-order',
    'nonce'   : '8cb16e3927',
    'post_id' :  89,
    'attachments[183]' : 2,
    'attachments[196]' : 3,
    'attachments[145]' : 1,
    'attachments[545]' : 4
}
```

Comment: what's the significance of the values against those `attachment[]` keys?  This question cannot be fully answered until you've said what those values represent.

Comment: i want to change attachment order using drag and drop. `attachments[183]` `183` is attachment id and `2` is order.

Comment: @Furgan order relative to what?  Their position in the list?

Comment: @Alnitak yes! order should according to list.

Comment: @Furqan that's what I guessed initially, but didn't submit an answer at first because the values in your example don't actually match the given order - they're in numeric order of attachment ID.  Given your list they should (if I understand you correctly) go 1, 2, 3, 4 rather than 2, 3, 1, 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with this object:

```
var query = {
    'action'  : 'save-attachment-order',
    'nonce'   : '8cb16e3927',
    'post_id' :  89,
}
```

You can add the ids as new properties with this:

```
$("#sortable li").each(function(){
    query[this.id] = 0; // not sure where you're getting the values from!
});
```

---

Now that you explained that the values are supposed to represent the order, you may want to use this instead (assuming jQuery UI):

```
var order = $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray" );
for(var i=0; i<order.length; i++) {
    query[order[i]] = i+1;
}
```

[Alnitak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294445/825789) should also work, as the the list items will be in order anyway.

Comment: 90% is working `query[this.id] = 0;` `0` will be the li order i did like this `$("#sortable li").each(function(index){
    query[this.id] = (index+1); // not sure where you're getting the values from!
});` 

but not working properly.

Comment: What about using `.sortable( "toArray" )` as I suggested? Is that a jQueryUI sortable?

Comment: yes! that i want. now its working properly. Thanks for Help :)

Comment: @Furqan odd, no reason I can see that the `.each()` version per my answer wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Yeah, that intrigued me too @Alnitak.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = [];

$('li').each(function() {
  ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: _please_ don't use `$(this).attr('id')` when `this.id` works perfectly well and is massively more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

This will add the IDs to `query`, with the value being the element's relative position in the list:

```
$('#sortable > li').each(function(ix) {
    query[this.id] = ix + 1;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qddc5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $("#sortable li").map(function(){
           return this.id;
          }).get();
```

This will fetch all the `li` ids as an array..

Comment: but the IDs won't be comma separated, they'll be an array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
object.property = value;
```

so your code become

```
$('#sortable li').each(function() {
  query[$(this).attr('id')]= 'vaule u want';
});
```

Comment: it's not `object.property`, it's `object[propertyName]` that's needed here.